How to create the access logs for secret manager without using cloudtrail.?
As per terraform configuration, for S3 and Redshift there is "logging" which used to capture the access logs of it. But for secret manager we don't have. How to achieve it using terraform ??
resource "aws_redshift_cluster" "example" {


dynamic "logging" {
for_each = local.enable_bucket_audit_log ? \[1\] : \[\]
content {
enable        = true
bucket_name   = aws_s3_bucket.redshift_audit_logs\[0\].id
s3_key_prefix = s3_audit_log_prefix
}
}

How to achieve it using terraform for "secret manager" since as per terraform documentation there is no logging for secret manager ??

You can't. Most AWS services don't have independent logs. S3 does because buckets can be used to hold static web content. Redshift does because databases traditionally provide several types of logs. For almost everything else, you need to use CloudTrail.

And in the future, please format any code that you post.

@kdgregory: I am very grateful for your help. Yes, continuing will submit the code in the proper manner.
